# Animate NSScrollView Magnification

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I would like to animate the `NSScrollView` magnification, but I cannot get it to work. Apple's documentation says that:

> To animate the magnification, use the object's animator. The default value is 1.0.

But when using `NSAnimationContext` the animation doesn't work.

```
NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({_ in

            NSAnimationContext.current.duration = 0.35

            self.scrollView.magnification = 1
            croppingView.animator().alphaValue = 1

            [...]
        }, completionHandler:{

            [...]
        })
```

XCode 10
macOS Mojave
Swift 4.2

Comment: Did you try the `NSScrollView`'s animator?

Comment: I haven't found any option for magnification in NSScrollview.animator().  :/

Comment: Try `self.scrollView.animator().magnification = 1`.

Comment: It doesn't work :/

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce the issue in a small test project?